# Sunspot Solr Not Working with a simple scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, solr, sunspot

Unless I'm high, I'm following the docs exactly but the scoping is still not working.  I'm not getting any errors, just an empty array in the results when I do the following:

```
search = Product.search do
  with(:website_id, 2)
end

@results = search.results
```

The response I get from the console is this:

```
=> <Sunspot::Search:{:fq=>["type:Product", "website_id_i:2"], :start=>0, :rows=>30, :q=>"*:*"}>
```

Here's what the code on my Product model looks like:

```
searchable do
  text :name
  integer :website_id
end
```

when I do the same search using "without", I actually get the record with website_id of 2.  I just dont understand why the scoping isn't working on the 'with' method.

I have updated to the latest version of both the `sunspot_rails` & `sunspot_solr` gems.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.  Had to reindex solr in order to reflect the changes made on my model.

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:stop
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex
```

Then, **restart your rails server**, **restart your console**, and all should be happy again in happy land.

Comment: You saved my sanity, my friend. Thanks for posting an answer to this.